# Read gzipped csv directly from a url in R

Tags: r, gzip

I'm looking to download a gzipped csv and load it as an R object without saving it first to disk. I can do this with zipped files but can't seem to get it to work with `gzfile` or `gzcon`.

Example:

```
grabRemote <- function(url) {
    temp <- tempfile()
    download.file(url, temp)
    aap.file <- read.csv(gzfile(temp), as.is = TRUE)
    unlink(temp)
    return(aap.file)
}
grabRemote("http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/articlefeedback/aa_combined-20110321.csv.gz")
```

That downloads a (small) gz compressed file containing [Wikipedia article feedback data](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Article_feedback/Data) (not important, but just to indicate it isn't giant or nefarious).

The code I have works fine but I feel like I'm missing something very obvious by resorting to creating and destroying a temporary file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am almost certain I answered this question once before.  The upshot is that **Connections** API of R (`file()`, `url()`, `pipe()`, ...) can do decompression on the fly, I do not think you can do it for remote http objects.

So do the very two-step you have described:  use `download.file()` with a `tempfile()` result as second argument to fetch the compressed file, and then read from it.   As `tempfile()` object, it will get cleaned up automatically at the end of your R session so the one minor fix I can suggest is to skip the `unlink()` (but then I like explicit cleanups, so you may as well keep it).

**Edit:** Got it:

```
con <- gzcon(url(paste("http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/articlefeedback/",
                       "aa_combined-20110321.csv.gz", sep="")))
txt <- readLines(con)
dat <- read.csv(textConnection(txt))

dim(dat)
# [1] 1490   19

summary(dat[,1:3])
# aa_page_id       page_namespace                 page_title  
# Min.   :     324   Min.   :0      United_States        :  79  
# 1st Qu.:   88568   1st Qu.:0      2011_NBA_Playoffs    :  52  
# Median : 2445733   Median :0      IPad_2               :  43  
# Mean   : 8279600   Mean   :0      IPod_Touch           :  38  
# 3rd Qu.:16179920   3rd Qu.:0      True_Grit_(2010_film):  38  
# Max.   :31230028   Max.   :0      IPhone_4             :  26  
# (Other)              :1214
```

The key was the hint the `gzcon` help that it can put decompression around an existing stream.  We then need the slight detour of `readLines` and reading via `textConnection` from that as `read.csv` wants to go back and forth in the data (to validate column width, I presume).

Comment: Yeah I'm almost 70% sure you or JD have answered something similar. I actually got the `tempfile` idea from a previous answer of yours regarding zipped folders. But I can't find something w/ gzfile/gzcon, which seem to behave differently from some of the other file or connection related functions.

Comment: Can you distill this down?  I actually used the same trick of 'streaming' out of a gzip`ed file way back in the early 1990s when disk space was scarcer and I kept simulation results gzip'ed.  So the ability to transparently get the "gunzip" functionality into a C library fread is pretty old-school and standard.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer for now. I might come back and give myself a better answer after some fooling around w/ gzcon (which seems like the more promising angle).

Comment: Thanks for the `gzcon` hint. That helped to solve the riddle.

Comment: Doesn't work with HTTPS:// links since `url()` does not support them.

Comment: It does with `method="libcurl"` under R 3.2.0 if R is built that way.  Else you can use `curl()` from the `curl` package as a drop-in replacement. See my `random` package.

Comment: As of R version 3.4, gzcon has a new `text=TRUE` argument that can simplify the above by eliminating the need for textConnection. The gzcon can then be used as a textConnection: `dat <- read.csv(gzcon('filename.csv.gz',text=TRUE))`

Comment: @MaxGhenis: I do not think that altering/editing somebody else's answer without stating so is a good idea.

Comment: I undid the edit and added as a separate answer. The long URL in the answer here slowed me down, so thought this would be useful.

Comment: Are you sure noodling around answers that are 8 and 10 years old is the best use of our time?

Comment: read.csv has issues parsing this example below. However zx8754 solution works. https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2022/2022-06/pageviews-20220611-050000.gz

Answer (score 2):

Using *data.table::fread* :

```
x <- data.table::fread("http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/articlefeedback/aa_combined-20110321.csv.gz")

dim(x)
[1] 1490   19

x[, 1:2]
#       aa_page_id page_namespace
#    1:   26224556              0
#    2:      31653              0
#    3:   26224556              0
#    4:   26224556              0
#    5:    1058990              0
#   ---                          
# 1486:     619464              0
# 1487:   19283361              0
# 1488:   19006979              0
# 1489:    5078775              0
# 1490:   30209619              0
```

Answer (score 1):

This function generalizes Dirk's answer:

```
R <- function(file_url) {
  con <- gzcon(url(file_url))
  txt <- readLines(con)
  return(read.csv(textConnection(txt)))
}
```