# Read and write csv.gz file in R

Tags: r, gzip

There are very [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548630/read-gzipped-csv-directly-from-a-url-in-r) questions about this topic, but non deals with this under R quite precisely.

I have a csv.gz file and I would like to "unzip" the file and have it as ordinary *.csv file. I suppose one would go about first reading the csv.gz file and latter via write.csv command create the csv file itself.

Here what I have tried a part of other things:

```
gz.file <- read.csv(gzfile(file.choose()), as.is = TRUE)
```

gives:

```
  head(gz.file)
        farmNo.milk.energy.vet.cows
  1     1;862533;117894;21186;121
  2     2;605764;72049;43910;80
  3     3;865658;158466;54583;95
  4     4;662331;66783;45469;87
  5     5;1003444;101714;81625;125
  6     6;923512;252408;96807;135
```

File claims to be data.frame but doesn't behave like one, what I'm missing here?

```
 class(gz.file)
 [1] "data.frame"
```

Once read into memory I would like to have it in pure csv file, so would write.csv would be the solution?

```
write.csv(gz.file, file="PATH")
```

Comment: You want `read.csv2` instead of `read.csv` to deal with semicolon separators.

Comment: Thanks Tomas. But it seems that just sep = ";" in ordinary read.csv solved my issues.

Answer (score 34):

In recent versions of `data.table` fast csv reader `fread` got support for csv.gz files. It automatically detects if it needs to decompress based on the filename so there is not much new to learn. Following should work.

```r
library(data.table)
dt = fread("data.csv.gz")
```

This feature requires extra, fortunately lightweight, dependency as you can read in [`?fread` manual](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/library/data.table/html/fread.html)

> Compressed files ending .gz and .bz2 are supported if the R.utils package is installed.

To write compressed argument use `fwrite(compress="gzip")`.

Comment: This is the answer, as far as I'm concerned. I hadn't realized data.table had added that functionality. Just make sure you have R utils `install.packages('R.utils')`. Don't even need to restart your session.

Answer (score 14):

`tidyverse`, particularly the `readr` package, has transparent support of `gzip` compressed files (and a few [others](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html#arguments))

```
library(readr)

read_csv("file.csv.gz") -> d

# write uncompressed data
d %>% write_csv("file.csv")
```

Comment: Just for completeness sake, the functions `read_csv` and `write_csv` are from the 
readr package.

Comment: In the code it should be library(tidyverse)  (you are missing the y en tidyverse)