# How can I use fread to read gz files in R?

Tags: r, windows, gzip, fread

I am on a windows machine trying to speed up the read.table step. My files are all .gz.

```
x=paste("gzip -c ",filename,sep="")
phi_raw = fread(x)

Error in fread(x) :
```

Cannot understand the error . Its a bit too cryptic for me.

Not a duplicate as suggested by zx8754:  using specifically in the context of fread. And while fread dows not have native support for gzip, this paradigm should work.  See http://www.molpopgen.org/coding/datatable.html

**Update**

Per suggestion below using system yields a longer error message - though i am still stuck.

```
Error in fread(system(x)) : 

  'input' must be a single character string containing a file name, a command, full path to a file, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or the input data itself

In addition: Warning message:


running command 'gzip -c D:/x_.gz' had status 1
```

**Update**

Running with gunzip as pointed out below:

```
Error in fread(system(x)) : 

  'input' must be a single character string containing a file name, a command, full path to a file, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or the input data itself

In addition: Warning message:

running command 'gunzip -c D:/XX_.gz' had status 127
```

note the different status

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/717

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decompress gz file using R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764499/decompress-gz-file-using-r)

Comment: Not a duplicate:  using specifically in the context of fread. And while fread dows not have native support for gzip, this paradigm should work.

Comment: Where is the error message? How about `fread(system(x))`?

Comment: Are we assured that your installation of Windoze has access to gzip and gunzip? Also noting that the cited article used gunzip rather than gzip.

Comment: Thanks - That did help in at least yielding the full error. See edit above.

Comment: gzip is certainly installed. and in the path. However - not sure what the status 1 is about in the error message. Same results with gunzip as well.

Comment: Are you all using windows? This is what I get when I try fread(file= "gzip -cd input.gz'):
 "Provided file 'gzip -cd input.gz' does not exists."

Comment: please have a look at [Read and write csv.gz file in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609758/read-and-write-csv-gz-file-in-r)

Answer (score 9):

`data.table` now supports reading .gz files directly with the `fread` function, provided that the [`R.utils`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.utils/index.html) package is installed.

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54379187/3330422) to a similar question, you can simply run the following:

```
library(data.table)
phi_raw <- fread("filename.gz")
```

Answer (score 6):

I often use gzip with fread on Windows.  It reads in the files without decompressing them.  I would try adding the -d option with the gzip command. Specifically, in your code, try `x=paste("gzip -dc ",filename,sep="")`.  Here is a reproducible example that works on my machine:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = letters[1:10])
write.table(df, 'df.txt', row.names = F, quote = F, sep = '\t')
system("which gzip")
system("gzip df.txt")
data.table::fread("gzip -dc df.txt")
```

And here is my `sessionInfo()`.

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rsconnect_0.4.3  tools_3.3.1      data.table_1.9.6 chron_2.3-47
```

I have successfully used gzip on Windows without adding a decompressed file to my hard drive using both Rtools (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and Gow (https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki).  If my reproducible example above does not work for you, use the `which gzip` and `which gunzip` commands to see the exact .exe that is running.  If it is not Rtools or Gow, perhaps try installing one of those two and trying the reproducible example again.