# Is there an efficient way to read a .gz file in R?

Tags: r, file, readfile, gzip

I have a huge .gz file with millions of data. I would like to read this .gz file in R as I want to do some manipulations to each of its line.
I tried:

```
gzf <- gzfile("myfile.gz", open = "r")  
f <- readLines(gzf)
```

However this takes forever in R and it gives me a memory error.
Is there an efficient way to read it?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727865/how-can-i-use-fread-to-read-gz-files-in-r

Comment: What format is your data?  `readr::read_csv` can directly read a gz file

Comment: @NelsonGon it gives a memory error: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 40.9 Gb. Is there a way around this?

Comment: It's really hard to tell but maybe try the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb