# Gzip encoded content URL

Tags: r, rcurl

I am having trouble trying to retrieve the gzip'd content of the following URL:

https://www.lendingclub.com/browse/browseNotesAj.action?method=getResultsInitial&startindex=0&pagesize=1

I can see that the content is encoded using gzip by looking at the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

I have tried RCurl using `getURL` as well as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548630/read-gzipped-csv-directly-from-a-url-in-r) with no luck.  Can someone help me try to get the content into a variable (hopefully without requiring writing and reading from file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or in `httr`

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
out <- GET("https://www.lendingclub.com/browse/browseNotesAj.action?method=getResultsInitial&startindex=0&pagesize=1")
jsonlite::fromJSON(content(out, "text"))
$result
[1] "success"

$searchresult
$searchresult$loans
loanGrade            purpose loanAmtRemaining loanUnfundedAmount noFee primeTotalInvestment                    title
1        C5 debt_consolidation               25                 25     0                    0 Debt consolidation
  isInCurrentOrder alreadySelected primeFractions    fico wholeLoanTimeRemaining loanType primeUnfundedAmount
1            FALSE           FALSE              0 720-724                 -69999 Personal                   0
  hasCosigner amountToInvest loan_status alreadyInvestedIn loanLength searchrank loanRateDiff loanGUID
1       FALSE              0   INFUNDING             FALSE         36          1          .00 35783459
  isWholeLoan loanAmt loanAmountRequested primeMarkedInvestment loanRate loanTimeRemaining
1           0    7650                7650                     0    14.99        1199721001

$searchresult$totalRecords
[1] 1472
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out RCurl handles gzip encoding:

```
getURL('https://www.lendingclub.com/browse/browseNotesAj.action?method=getResultsInitial&startindex=0&pagesize=1', 
       encoding="gzip")
```