# How do I load a remote .Rdata file in R?

Tags: r

I am attempting to load a .Rdata file without having to download the actual file to my computer.

Here is what I have so far:

```
primate_URL <- "https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE118nnn/GSE118546/suppl/GSE118546_macaque_fovea_all_10X_Jan2018.Rdata.gz"
con <- gzcon(url(primate_URL))
load(con)
```

When I run the script, it returns this error:

```
Error in load(con) : 
  the input does not start with a magic number compatible with loading from a connection
```

Any tips on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @akrun I attempted your method, and it loaded something, although it looks to be corrupted: https://imgur.com/c97eBya

Comment: I didn't download it fully as it was a big file.

Comment: sorry, forgot it is `.Rdata`

Comment: btw, I'm trying to load the file into memory without downloading to my computer. I'm looking for something similar to this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/55308162/12212260).

Answer (score 0):

Try following. I tried it with a small file from the same source of same type.

```
primate_URL <- "https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE118nnn/GSE118992/suppl/GSE118992_supplementaryData.Rdata.gz"

download.file(primate_URL, "GSE118992_supplementaryData.Rdata.gz")

file.x <- gzfile("GSE118992_supplementaryData.Rdata.gz", open = "r")
file.x.data <- readLines(file.x, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: I was hoping to load the file directly into memory, similar to this post for csv files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55308162/12212260.