# R - read.csv via a link on a web site

Tags: r

I would like to access data from the below website using R rather than manually downloading, unzipping and saving to my computer. For example, I am trying to get the Seasonal (Winter) data.

https://www.nodc.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/OC5/woa18/woa18.pl?parameter=t

I tried the below code but it didn't work (as I expected) and Googling hasn't helped me solve the issue (I may not be using the best search terms...). Any ideas are appreciated!

```
Sil_JFM<-read.csv("https://www.nodc.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/OC5/woa18/woa18.pl?parameter=t/t13mn01.csv")
```

Comment: The correct links is: "https://data.nodc.noaa.gov/woa/WOA18/DATA/temperature/csv/decav/1.00/woa18_decav_t13mn01.csv.gz" You need to right click on the csv file hyperlink to get the link. Also, it is gzipped file, maybe try using `data.table::fread()`.

Comment: Related post on how to read gzipped files from web: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9548630/680068